# Parse JSON from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, json, google-api, google-sheets

**EDIT:** `entry.content.$t` is the wrong field to access individual cells. **entry.gsx$[*cell column header*]** is the correct method. Apologies and thanks for helping to solve this.

Original question:

I'm trying to parse [JSON data from a Google Spreadsheet](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/json.html). The problem is, the entries field returns a string that is an entire row of the spreadsheet—but appears as a malformed object. How are other people parsing this data? Here is what the content node looks like:

```
"content":
{
    "type"   :"text",
    "$t"     :"location: 780 Valencia St San Francisco, CA 94110,
               phonenumber: (555) 555-5555,
               website: http://www.780cafe.com,
               latitude: 37.760505,
               longitude: -122.421447"
},
```

Look carefully, the `$t` field returns an entire string which is a row in the Google spreadsheet. So `entry.content.$t` returns a string: `location: 780 Valencia St San Francisco, CA 94110, phonenumber: (555) 555-5555...`

Further exacerbating this issue is that some of the cells in the spreadsheet have commas (like addresses) which aren't escaped or quoted. Something like

```
jQuery.parseJSON(entry.content.$t)
```

or

```
eval('('+ entry.content.$t + ')')
```

throws an error. I suppose regex is an option, but I'm hoping others may have solved this in a more elegant way. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is the request you use to get the JSON data? Do you use type cells or type list? (see http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample.html)

Comment: Looking at the examples further, I think you're doing something wrong - either in how you're requesting the JSON or in the spreadsheet data itself.  From what I can see, you shouldn't receive an entire row as a text field; you should be getting a combination of objects and arrays in your data to denote rows and columns.

Comment: Doh! I figured it out. You got it. I was extracting the wrong node. Apparently, it does return individual objects for each cell. My mistake. THanks so much for catching this.

Comment: I had the same problem. Looks like I was using /public/basic at the end of the URL. It should have been /public/values.

Answer (score 1):

The "text" inside the `$t` attribute is not JSON.  According to the documentation, text nodes are transfomed in to `$t` attributes, so you cannot rely on anything in there being properly formatted JSON.

I would suggest using a regular expression instead, though I will warn you that to parse that output will require some fancy stuff.  You'll end up using an assertion since you can't split on commas - you'll have to search for `(\w+):` but in order to find the next element, you'll have to take in everything up to another matching `(\w+):`, but also not gobble it up.  It can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Just recently, I had the very same problem.

To parse content of *$t*, you can use this RegEx:

```
/(\w+): (.+?(?=(?:, \w+:|$)))/mgi
```

it will return pairs of key-value.

JavaScript example:

```
    var currentPropertiesText = jsonEntry['content']['$t'];

    // var propsArray = currentPropertiesText.split(", ");
    var re = /(\w+): (.+?(?=(?:, \w+:|$)))/mgi;
    var propsArray = re.exec(currentPropertiesText)
    var props = {};

    while (propsArray != null) {

        var propName = propsArray[1];
        var propValue = propsArray[2];

        props[propName] = propValue;

        propsArray = re.exec(currentPropertiesText);
    }
```

That should help :-)